# replace all punctuation in string with another string in python

Tags: python, string, replace, bigdata, punctuation

i want to replace all punctuation with string "PUNCTUATION"

. I have  many long string , so i need an efficient code.

for example i have some string like this

```
s = "Hello. World, Awesome! Really?"
```

i want the output to become something like this

```
replaced_s = "Hello PUNCTUATION World PUNCTUATION Awesome PUNCTUATION Really PUNCTUATION"
```

i think i can use replace but wont it take too long?
any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `string.punctuation`

```
import string
s = "Hello. World, Awesome! Really?"
for c in string.punctuation:
    s = s.replace(c,' PUNCTUATION ')
s
#'Hello PUNCTUATION  World PUNCTUATION  Awesome PUNCTUATION  Really PUNCTUATION '
```

Or use regex:

```
import re
s = "Hello. World, Awesome! Really?"
s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]',' PUNCTUATION ',s)
re.sub(' +', ' ',s)
#'Hello PUNCTUATION World PUNCTUATION Awesome PUNCTUATION Really PUNCTUATION '
```